# Inline CSS ending with three dots

Tags: css

Isn't it wrong that css style ends with three dots? This is a screenshot of my browser devtools screen, you can see before the closing `</style>` tag it reads `display: inli...`. What does that mean? It is from my vue-cli project.

[image]

Comment: could you be more specific about your question. What do you mean by three dots?

Comment: @alexortizl, as you can see before closing style tag there dots and no closing brackets. .pure-form-message-inline { display: inli...

Answer (score 1):

It happens when your content is too long. Chrome devtools doesn't show all the content, instead it shows some of it followed by `...` to indicate that there is more content after. Probably you have a lot of styles and that's why this is happening.